# jquery - 2 ajax calls simultaneously

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to run 2 AJAX calls simultaneously. I tried the below code but it waits for `ajax ({export.php})` to finish and then `ajax({display.php})` is run.

I want to run these 2 AJAX calls at the same time. For example, while export.php is running it should also run display.php at same time. How can I do this?

When I click on a button it calls export.php to convert the database table to a CSV file. I also want to show the progress bar i.e. how many records have finished, `1%`, `2%`... `100%`. That percentage value is written in the display.php file so to make a progress bar I need to run the 2 AJAX calls simultaneously.

```js
$('.tocsv').on('click', function() {
  var display = setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'display.php',
      method: 'get',
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
  }, 500);

  $.ajax({
    url: 'export.php',
    method: 'post',
    success: function() {
      clearInterval(display);
    }
  });
});
```

**Edit**
The problem was in display.php file i had written `session_start()`. I just deleted that line and changed ajax code to this

```
                url: 'display.php?file=<?=session_id()?>',
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#res').html(data);
                }
            });
```

but why it doesn't work when i write session_start() ?

Comment: Your code is already running both requests simultaneously. The problem may be because your server is configured to deny multiple concurrent connections, or is not fast enough to deal with the CSV generation and also you flooding it with AJAX requests every 500ms

Comment: but i am getting output in console at last.

Comment: "*but i am getting output in console at last*" - what does this mean?  Do you mean "getting console output last"?

Comment: i am getting output after export.php finishes.

Answer (score 1):

In AJAX the first alphabet A is for "Asynchronous". So calling asyn way is not the issue here. The problem is with making ajax request inside the setInterval. I am very sure that you server is not responding in the time delay you have given i.e. 500ms and you are flooding your server with multiple request every half second. By the time one request is completed you have made at least 4 or 5 request to your server which is the root cause of you issue. Remove setInterval and if you want you call to be made after 0.5 sec use setTimeout.